# Dynamic Class Creation in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, metaprogramming, metaclass, declarative

We have a need to create SQLAlchemy classes to access multiple external data sources that will increase in number over time.  We use the declarative base for our core ORM models and I know we can manually specify new ORM classes using the autoload=True to auto generate the mapping.

The problem is that we need to be able generate them dynamically taking something like this:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
Base = declarative_base()

stored={}
stored['tablename']='my_internal_table_name'
stored['objectname']='MyObject'
```

and turning it into something like this dynamically:

```
class MyObject(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'my_internal_table_name'
    __table_args__ = {'autoload':True}
```

We don't want the classes to persist longer than necessary to open a connection, perform the queries, and then closing the connection.  Therefore, ideally, we can put the items in the "stored" variable above into a database and pull them as needed.  The other challenge is that the object name (e.g. "MyObject") may be used on different connections so we cannot define it once and keep it around.

Any suggestions on how this might be accomplished would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks...

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can dynamically create `MyObject` using the [3-argument call to `type`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#type):

```
type(name, bases, dict)

    Return a new type object. This is essentially a dynamic form of the 
    class statement...
```

For example:

```
mydict={'__tablename__':stored['tablename'],
        '__table_args__':{'autoload':True},}

MyObj=type(stored['objectname'],(Base,),mydict)
print(MyObj)
# <class '__main__.MyObject'>
print(MyObj.__base__)
# <class '__main__.Base'>
print(MyObj.__tablename__)
# my_internal_table_name
print(MyObj.__table_args__)
# {'autoload': True}
```

Comment: boy...i feel dumb.  Such a simple solution.  I didn't realize the type method was so powerful.

I modified the solution slightly to put the object name in the global space so it could be included in SQLAlchemy queries directly:

globals()[stored['objectname']]=type(stored['objectname'],(Base,),mydict)

Thanks...great solution.

Comment: Don't feel dumb! I learned this trick by watching others use it here on SO. Now you know the trick too and can wow your friends. :)

Comment: @unutbu do you need the additional separating comas so the calling to type realize they are just the first arguments?

Comment: this thread is kind of old but, I can't find the solution anywhere, how can I reuse the MyObj somewhere else during an api call?
Because if I call the factory two times, an error saying that the tablename already exists is thrown