# Wrap SQLAlchemy in Classes in Python

Tags: python, sqlite, python-2.7, sqlalchemy

I am using SQLAlchemy 1.0.6 and Python 2.7.6.  After the great insight I gleaned from my last post ([Dynamic Datasets and SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31325860/dynamic-datasets-and-sqlalchemy/31325947#31325947)), I am now looking to modularize my code for easier implementation into my framework.  Going from this full-working code

```
from time import time
from sqlalchemy import Column, String, Integer
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

Base = declarative_base()
class Empty_Init():
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):   
        for k,v in kwargs.items():
            #This class and the structure of the table need to be sync'd.
               if hasattr(self, k):
                setattr(self, k, v)
               else:
                if k not in engine.execute("SELECT * FROM `{tbl}`".format(tbl = self.__tablename__))._metadata.keys:
                    engine.execute("ALTER TABLE `{tbl}` ADD COLUMN {col} {typ}".format(
                                tbl = self.__tablename__, 
                                col = k,
                                typ = "INT" if type(v) is int else ("DOUBLE" if type(v) is float else "VARCHAR")))
                setattr(self.__class__, k, Column(k, String))
                setattr(self, k, v)

class Listing(Empty_Init, Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Listings'
    __table_args__ = {'sqlite_autoincrement': True}
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    make = Column(String)
    model = Column(String)
    year = Column(Integer)

t = time()

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///')
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

session = sessionmaker()
session.configure(bind=engine)
s = session()

try:
    data = {'make':'Chevy',
        'model' : 'Corvette',
        'year' : 1964,
        'doors' : 2,
        'price' : 50000}
    record = Listing(**data)
    s.add(record)

    data = {'make':'Chevy',
        'model' : 'Camaro',
        'year' : 1967,
        'doors' : 2,
        'HP' : 375,
        "0-60" : 6.1}
    record = Listing(**data)
    s.add(record)

    s.commit() #attempt to commit the changes   
except:
    s.rollback() #rollback the changes on error
finally:
    s.close() #Close the connection
print str(time() - t) + " s."
```

(Note:  the purpose of the Empty_Init class is to have it be inherited to other tables, as seen in the Listing class.)

I'd like to

- wrap the SQLAlchemy-related things into it's own self-contained class
- Port the SQLAlchemy-related classes into it's own module via `import`

Thinking that the first goal needs to be achieved before the second, here's where I'm stuck

```
from time import time
from sqlalchemy import Column, String, Integer
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

class DataBase(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.Base = declarative_base()
        self.engine = create_engine('sqlite:///')
        self.session = sessionmaker()
        self.session.configure(bind=self.engine)
        self.s = self.session()
        self.Base.metadata.create_all(self.engine)

    def Add_Record(self, data):
        record = Listing(self.engine, self.Base, **data)        
        self.s.add(record)

    def Commit(self):
        self.s.commit()

class Empty_Init():
    def __init__(self, engine, Base, **kwargs): 
        for k,v in kwargs.items():
            #This class and the structure of the table need to be sync'd.
               if hasattr(self, k):
                setattr(self, k, v)
               else:
                if k not in engine.execute("SELECT * FROM `{tbl}`".format(tbl = self.__tablename__))._metadata.keys:
                    engine.execute("ALTER TABLE `{tbl}` ADD COLUMN {col} {typ}".format(
                                tbl = self.__tablename__, 
                                col = k,
                                typ = "INT" if type(v) is int else ("DOUBLE" if type(v) is float else "VARCHAR")))
                setattr(self.__class__, k, Column(k, String))
                setattr(self, k, v)

class Listing(Empty_Init):
    __tablename__ = 'Listings'
    __table_args__ = {'sqlite_autoincrement': True}
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    make = Column(String)
    model = Column(String)
    year = Column(Integer)

t = time()

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///')

DBC = DataBase()
data = {'make':'Chevy',
    'model' : 'Corvette',
    'year' : 1964,
    'price' : 50000}
DBC.Add_Record(data)

data = {'make':'Chevy',
    'model' : 'Camaro',
    'year' : 1967,
    'HP' : 375,
    "0-60" : 6.1}
DBC.Add_Record(data)
DBC.Commit()

print str(time() - t) + " s."
```

Running this gives the following full Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 540, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "/home/manny/sqlalchemy_basic_master_class.py", line 65, in <module>
    DBC.Add_Record(data)
  File "/home/manny/sqlalchemy_basic_master_class.py", line 23, in Add_Record
    record = Listing(self.engine, self.Base, **data)        
  File "/home/manny/sqlalchemy_basic_master_class.py", line 40, in __init__
    if k not in engine.execute("SELECT * FROM `{tbl}`".format(tbl = self.__tablename__))._metadata.keys:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1987, in execute
    return connection.execute(statement, *multiparams, **params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 906, in execute
    return self._execute_text(object, multiparams, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1054, in _execute_text
    statement, parameters
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1146, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1341, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    exc_info
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 199, in raise_from_cause
    reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1139, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 450, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: Listings [SQL: 'SELECT * FROM `Listings`']
```

I understand what the error is saying (the database was created, but there are no tables), but why?  Why didn't SQLAlchemy create the table?  I executed the same code in the same sequence under DataBase's `__init__`.  What's even more baffling, is that if I run the first code, then initialize the `DataBase` class by inheriting the `Base` and `engine` SQLAlchemy classes, like so

```
class DataBase(object):
    def __init__(self, Base, engine):
        self.Base = Base
        self.engine = engine
        self.session = sessionmaker()
        self.session.configure(bind=self.engine)
        self.s = self.session()
        self.Base.metadata.create_all(self.engine)
Base = declarative_base()
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///')
DBC = DataBase(Base, engine)
```

and run its methods, it writes to the database perfectly, so I strongly suspect I'm not inheriting SQLAlchemy's classes correctly (in the 2nd code) or, to a much lesser degree, I'm not letting SQLAlchemy's behind-the-scenes magic work by wrapping it into a class -- I just can't see why.  Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Looks like you still need to call `create_all()`...

Comment: Isn't that what I did with `self.Base.metadata.create_all(self.engine)` ?

Comment: You are right, i must have missed it. Another idea: could it be that the call `engine = create_engine('sqlite:///')` second time (not in the `Database.__init__` just voids your in-memory database? What if you try and delete it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update:  I think I was correct in thinking that the way I was trying to structure my classes wasn't letting SQLAlchemy's behind-the-scenes magic work. Thus, after playing around with the class inheritance, this full-working code works perfectly fine:

```
from time import time
from sqlalchemy import Column, String, Integer
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

Base = declarative_base()
class DataBase(object):
    def __init__(self, Base):
        self.Base = Base
        self.engine = create_engine('sqlite:///')
        self.session = sessionmaker()
        self.session.configure(bind=self.engine)
        self.s = self.session()
        self.Base.metadata.create_all(self.engine)

    def Add_Record(self, data):
        record = Listing(self.engine, **data)
        self.s.add(record)

    def Commit(self):
        self.s.commit()

    def Close(self):
        self.s.close()


class Empty_Init():
    def __init__(self, engine, **kwargs):
        #This class and the structure of the table need to be sync'd.
        for k,v in kwargs.items():
               if hasattr(self, k): #if the class already has the attribute initialized,
                setattr(self, k, v) # then assign it the new value
               else: # if it doesn't...
                if k not in engine.execute("SELECT * FROM `{tbl}`".format(tbl = self.__tablename__))._metadata.keys:
                    engine.execute("ALTER TABLE `{tbl}` ADD COLUMN {col} {typ}".format(
                                tbl = self.__tablename__,
                                col = k,
                                typ = "INT" if type(v) is int else ("DOUBLE" if type(v) is float else "VARCHAR")))
                setattr(self.__class__, k, Column(k, String))
                setattr(self, k, v)


class Listing(Empty_Init, Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Listings'
    __table_args__ = {'sqlite_autoincrement': True}
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    make = Column(String)
    model = Column(String)
    year = Column(Integer)


t = time()

DBC = DataBase(Base)

data = {'make':'Chevy',
    'model' : 'Corvette',
    'year' : 1964,
    'price' : 50000}
DBC.Add_Record(data)

data = {'make':'Chevy',
    'model' : 'Camaro',
    'year' : 1967,
    'doors' : 2,
    'wheels_rwd' : 4.1,
    "test" : "bladads"}
DBC.Add_Record(data)
DBC.Commit()
DBC.Close()

print str(time() - t) + " s."
```

Note the slight variation in the class inheritance.

Now that the first goal is complete, I would like to move onto the second of placing `DataBase`, `Empty_Init`, and `Listing` into an external module.  This is part was a bit tricky, but here's how it all works together

main.py

```
from time import time
from datetime import datetime
import sqla_lib

t = time()

DBC = sqla_lib.DataBase(sqla_lib.Base)

data = {'make':'Chevy',
    'model' : 'Corvette',
    'year' : 1964,
    'price' : 50000}
DBC.Add_Record(data)

data = {'make':'Chevy',
    'model' : 'Camaro',
    'year' : 1967,
    'doors' : 2,
    'wheels_rwd' : 4.1,
    "test" : "bladads"}
DBC.Add_Record(data)
DBC.Commit()
DBC.Close()

print str(time() - t) + " s."
```

sqla_lib.py

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, String, Integer
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

Base = declarative_base()
class DataBase(object):
    def __init__(self, Base):
        self.Base = Base
        self.engine = create_engine('sqlite:///')
        self.session = sessionmaker()
        self.session.configure(bind=self.engine)
        self.s = self.session()
        self.Base.metadata.create_all(self.engine)

    def Add_Record(self, data):
        record = self.Listing(self.engine, **data)
        self.s.add(record)

    def Commit(self):
        self.s.commit()

    def Close(self):
        self.s.close()


    class Empty_Init():
        def __init__(self, engine, **kwargs):
            #This class and the structure of the table need to be sync'd.
            for k,v in kwargs.items():
                   if hasattr(self, k): #if the class already has the attribute initialized,
                    setattr(self, k, v) # then assign it the new value
                   else: # if it doesn't...
                    if k not in engine.execute("SELECT * FROM `{tbl}`".format(tbl = self.__tablename__))._metadata.keys:
                        engine.execute("ALTER TABLE `{tbl}` ADD COLUMN {col} {typ}".format(
                                    tbl = self.__tablename__,
                                    col = k,
                                    typ = "INT" if type(v) is int else ("DOUBLE" if type(v) is float else "VARCHAR")))
                    setattr(self.__class__, k, Column(k, String))
                    setattr(self, k, v)


    class Listing(Empty_Init, Base):
        __tablename__ = 'Listings'
        __table_args__ = {'sqlite_autoincrement': True}
        id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
        make = Column(String)
        model = Column(String)
        year = Column(Integer)
```

Since I'm still new at SQLAlchemy, I welcome any feedback you may have.  But since this solves my two goals, I will mark this question as solved.  I hope that it may help someone in the future.