# Sqlalchemy dynamically create table and mapped class

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, metaprogramming, metaclass, declarative

Given a set of column names and their types, the goal is to
to instantiate a  table and the corresponding mapped class.

It is related to question posted here: [Dynamic Class Creation in SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2768607/dynamic-class-creation-in-sqlalchemy).

So far I have the following:

```
table = Table(tbl, 
              metadata, 
             *(Column(col, ctype, primary_key=pk, index=idx) for  col,  ctype, pk, idx in zip(attrs, types, primary_keys, indexes))
              )
```

This creates the table object. Now I need to create the corresponding class.

```
mydict={'__tablename__':tbl}
cls = type(cls_name, (Base,), mydict)
```

This gives me following error:

> ArgumentError: Mapper Mapper|persons_with_coord|t_persons_w_coord could not assemble any primary key columns for mapped table

My question is how do I specify the primary keys as part of the class creation. 
And after the class is created do I need to call mapper as follows:

```
mapper(cls, table)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `mydict` mapping has to either include a table object or specify that the table needs to be loaded from the database.

This should work

```
mydict={'__tablename__':tbl, '__table__': table}
```

This should also work

```
mydict={'__tablename__':tbl, '__table_args__': ({'autoload':True},)}
```

the primary keys are already specified when you create `table`. It shouldn't be necessary to specify them again when creating a declarative, however if it required (say, for a complex key), it should be specified in `__table_args__`.

The mapper has to be called on a declarative class. However, the newly created declarative doesn't have a metadata object. Adding the metadata will make the dynamically created declarative behave *more* like a regular declarative, so I would recommend putting this line after class creation

```
cls.metadata = cls.__table__.metadata
```

so, the full edits could be:

```
mydict={'__tablename__':tbl, '__table__': table}
cls = type(cls_name, (Base,), mydict)
cls.metadata = cls.__table__.metadata
```