# SQLAlchemy create dynamic tables and columns

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to create db tables and columns dynamically in line with the data I retrieve.
I retrieve a list of databases, a list of column names and attributes such as column type, primary_key / unique, nullable as well as other metadate.
I'm trying to use this information to create the tables dynamically and have been using the forum posts to get a better idea of how to achieve this. So I want to create the tables based on the information I retrieve - database and the column information (colnames and column type, primary key and nullable information. This information retrieved could change daily or weekly.
Forum post #1 - [Sqlalchemy dynamically create table and mapped class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42260976/sqlalchemy-dynamically-create-table-and-mapped-class)

```
postgresql_db = engine(...)

post_meta = sql.MetaData(bind=postgresql_db.engine)

post_meta.reflect(schema='customers')

connection = postgresql_db.engine.connect()

col_names = ['id', 'fname', 'lname', 'age']
ctype = ['Integer', 'String', 'String', 'Integer']
pk = ['True', 'False', 'False', 'False']
nulls = ['No', 'No', 'No', 'No']

class test(object):

     test = Table('customers', post_meta,
              *(Column(col, ctype, primary_key=pk, nullable=nulls)
           for col, ctype, pk, nulls in zip(col_names, ctype, pk, nulls))

test.create()
```

There is an error message: 
`AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute _set_parent_with_dispatch`
Can't seem to identify what this error is referring to exactly.

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/xxx/db.py", line 247, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/xxx/db.py", line 168, in main
    for col, ctype, pk, nulls in zip(col_names, ctype, pk, nulls)
  File "C:/Users/xxx/apidb.py", line 168, in <genexpr>
    for col, ctype, pk, nulls in zip(col_names, ctype, pk, nulls)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\schema.py", line 1234, in __init__
    self._init_items(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\schema.py", line 79, in _init_items
    item._set_parent_with_dispatch(self)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute '_set_parent_with_dispatch'
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please include the full traceback including line numbers etc.

Comment: i recommend you to start working with SQLAlchemy from [tutorial](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html)

Comment: @AzatIbrakov thanks for the information and you solution worked for me. I've been reading the tutorial off and on for a while, possibly I need to aquire more knowledge on a wider base.

Comment: it means that you are passing `list` object `ctype` as argument to `Column` initializer's `type_` parameter but it supposed to be one of `TypeEngine` subclasses (like `String` and `Integer`)

Comment: seems like `SQLAlchemy` failing on statement `self.type._set_parent_with_dispatch(self)` in `Column` initializer where `type` is set to your `ctype` `list` object

Answer (score 12):

There are many things that are not correct here.

`nullable` parameter in `Column` initializer should have type `bool`, but you are trying to pass a `str` object `nulls`, same thing for `pk` and `primary_key` parameter.

Furthermore, you are trying to overwrite names `ctype`, `pk`, `nulls` in comprehension, which is not correct and raises given exception.
You should rename objects generated from `zip` in comprehension.

`SQLAlchemy` won't recognize strings `'Integer'`, `'String'`, they are not valid `Column` types.

If you want to reflect specific table called `'customers'`, it should be done using parameter `only`, not `schema`, and it should be `list` of names.

Also you don't need class `test`.

Your code can look like

```
from sqlalchemy import MetaData, Table, Column, Integer, String

postgresql_db = engine(...)

post_meta = MetaData(bind=postgresql_db.engine)

post_meta.reflect(only=['customers'])

connection = postgresql_db.engine.connect()

columns_names = ['id', 'fname', 'lname', 'age']
columns_types = [Integer, String, String, Integer]
primary_key_flags = [True, False, False, False]
nullable_flags = [False, False, False, False]

test = Table('customers', post_meta,
             *(Column(column_name, column_type,
                      primary_key=primary_key_flag,
                      nullable=nullable_flag)
               for column_name,
                   column_type,
                   primary_key_flag,
                   nullable_flag in zip(columns_names,
                                        columns_types,
                                        primary_key_flags,
                                        nullable_flags)))

test.create()
```

Finally, if you do `post_meta.reflect(only=['customers'])` and it works, given table can be obtained simply by

```
test = post_meta.tables['customers']
```

without constructing from scratch.

Comment: thats for the solution. The mistakes were quite basic, thanks for pointing them out

Comment: do you have access to source database?

Comment: no. All information is retrieved through the end points, I don't have direct access to the source database.

Comment: How can I add something to this newly created table?

Comment: @MasonChoi: you should ask a new question since it is not related to OP