# SQLAlchemy dynamic class object for Tables

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

This is a follow-up to a post I opened regarding the creation of dynamic tables and columns using SQLALCHEMY. [SQLAlchemy create dynamic tables and columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43721680/sqlalchemy-create-dynamic-tables-and-columns/43721876?noredirect=1#comment74493419_43721876)

Most of the tutorials that show how to create dynamic Tables and columns in Python and SQLAlchemy focus on creating a class object - using `Declarative`, such that every use of a class creates a table with the pre-defined columns and column metadata defined in that class (see below). The problem with this way of creating tables is that at least as I understand it, does not allow me to create columns dynamically as well. I am reading an API and attaining metadata for tables which can change daily, therefore I need a method of creating these tables dynamically - see my orignal post: [SQLAlchemy create dynamic tables and columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43721680/sqlalchemy-create-dynamic-tables-and-columns/43721876?noredirect=1#comment74493419_43721876)

The following construct for instance does not allow for creating dynamic columns for tables, as far as I understand it, such like my original post:

```
    Base = declarative_base()

    class User(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'users'

        id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
        name = Column(String)
        fullname = Column(String)
        password = Column(String)
```

The reason I ask about class objects in this regard, is because the tutorials that show how to query the database require the use of a class object in the query. 
So for instance, every method I've researched of querying the database to find the lastest value in each table (maximum `id` assuming it is the primary key or maximum `timestamp`) seems to require the use of a class object which currently I am not doing.

```
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()
User.query.order_by('timestamp desc').limit(1)
```

1. Is it possible to Is it possible to construct a class object that will create dynamic columns? Using a class object ?
2. If not, Is there another best-practice for querying the database using SQLAlchemy to find the latest record in a table ?

See this blog post on SQLAlchemy - [Great tutorial, i've read](http://williamqliu.github.io/2015/05/15/sqlalchemy.html#ormdatamapper).

Comment: I'm stuck here aswell. Have you found a solution to this?

Comment: This blog http://sparrigan.github.io/sql/sqla/2016/01/03/dynamic-tables.html goes in the right direction but I need to be able to use an object class.